# Session is null when redirecting to previous page

Tags: php, html, session, referrer

I am storing a value in Session in php. While redirecting using http referrer, the Session is turned out to null. Is there any way of retaining the session when we use the http referrer?

Comment: Whats your code? Have you forgotten session_start() on the detination page?

Comment: Please provide code so we can understand the exact problem

Comment: Stop worring about the referrer, it doesn't really matter how the user got on the page. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: I would need to see what you are doing, especially how you are setting the session value, and how  you are reading it on the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a shot in the dark.

Before you use the `$_SESSION` variable, you must call `session_start()`. `$_SESSION` may be null if the session hasn't started yet.